# How to able to select and input at the same time in the same line?

Tags: html, asp.net

I have done the code which able to select only

```
<div class="form-group">
                        <label for="editAppointmentContact" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Customer Name</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <select class="form-control select2contact" id="editAppointmentContact" ></select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

and the other line to input

```
<div class="form-group">
                        <label for="editAppointmentContact" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Customer Name</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <input class="form-control"  id="editAppointmentContact" type="text" >
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

How can I make these two select and input at the same time in the same line?

Comment: Do you want both select and input box in the same line?

Comment: I want the box can do both, select and input

Comment: for clarification, do you want to type to search the options available for select or do you want to type in the input when there is no desired option?

Comment: @ShahriarMahmudSajid , I want to type in the input when there is no desired option

Answer (score 0):

Like you use bootstrap, you can use form-inline. Look the docs :

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/forms/#inline-forms

Try to adapt this layout to your case.

(And I give you an advice, you shouldn't use 2 times the same id in html for different element, as you did with select and text input)

Hope it will helps,
Best regards !

Comment: I want the box can do both, select and input

Comment: Oh yes I understand, so you should look for select2 : 

https://select2.org/getting-started/basic-usage

Comment: I want to type in the input when there is no desired option